# Solving $x = \frac13\sec(a)$ for $a$ (after integrating via trig substitution)

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, graphing-functions

For the integral $\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{9x^2-1}}$, I decided to use $x = \frac13\sec(a)$. The expression simplifies to the integral of $1$, simply becoming $a$.

The issue is making $a$ the subject of $x = \frac13\sec(a)$. By drawing a triangle of hypotenuse $3x$, base length $1$ and height of $(9x^2 -1)^{1/2}$, where $a$ is the angle between $3x$ and $1$. I end up with three expressions for $a$:

$$a = \arctan\left(\sqrt{9x^2-1}\right) \quad\text{or}\quad
\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{9x^2-1}}{3x}\right)\quad\text{or}\quad 
\arccos\left(\dfrac{1}{3x}\right)$$

After graphing all three on Desmos, only the first answer was right, however I don’t know why, and is it always the arctan that’s right? What assumption is being made for the sine and cosine variation that makes the integral incorrect?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this may have to do with dropping the absolute value signs around $\sqrt{\tan^2 a} = |\tan a|$ in the denominator, but I'm not quite sure so I'll just leave that here as food for thought

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should include $C$ as a constant since it is an idefinite integral.
Now you know that the domain of *$\arcsin$* and *$\arcsin$* differ from that of *$\arctan$* which is defined for all values of $x$. I think the problem might be the way you are plotting the solutions. You have to specify which range of $x$ values you are using.

Comment: Yes, the +c definitely. In terms of domain, It doesn’t specify, I just assumed all real x.

Comment: Since your integral is indefinite you get an integration constant term after solving it. This integrating constant can change the answer. Actually indefinite integration gives us a family of curves.
Definite integration is nothing but summation of small parts. Definite integration we get only one answer.